# Can you figure out what I am?

Tags: riddle

1. I can not be stretched, though it may feel like it.
2. I am important for a lot of things: I am relevant for music, for sports and in my absence everyday life would fail.
3. I am expensive. Some people consider me one of the most expensive things there are.
4. When I become too little, most things will break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> Time

I can not be stretched, though it may feel like it.

> people try to stretch time.  Unsuccessfully.

I am important for a lot of things: I am relevant for music, for sports and in my absence everyday life would fail.

> Time in music and sports is important.   It is also needed in everyday life!

I am expensive. Some people consider me one of the most expensive things there are.

> Time IS money!

When I become too little, most things will break.

> You get in a hurry and cut corners without enough time

Comment: wow, didn't expect this to be solved in ~5 minutes... My point in the last line was the Planck Time though. But you are still right.

Comment: Not a big fan of [this theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity#Gravitational_time_dilation_and_frequency_shift) about the stretchiness then? :-)

Comment: @Bass True, but it isn't very practical when you have a deadline.  On the other hand, a boring activity sure does seem to stretch on and on.